# Question about the definition of closed subschemes in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

In Hartshorne page 85, closed subschemes are defined to be the following.

A closed immersion is a morphism of schemes $f: Y \to X$ such that $f$ induces a homeomorphism of $sp(Y)$ onto a closed subset of $sp(X)$ , and the induced map $f^{\#}: O_X \to f_*O_Y$ of sheaves on $X$ is surjective. A closed subscheme of $X$ is an equivalence class of closed immersions, where $f: Y \to X$ and $f': Y' \to X$ is equivalent if there exists an isomorphism $i: Y' \to Y$ such that $f' = f\circ i$.

Then he explains in II Example 3.2.3 that $A \to A/ \mathfrak{a}$ induces a closed immersion from $Spec(A/\mathfrak{a}) \to Spec A$. So we can see $V(\mathfrak{a})$ as a closed subscheme of $Spec A$.

What I don't understand is how is the sheaf structure on $V(\mathfrak{a})$ actually defined? Any explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To say that a subscheme is an equivalence class of anything is the height of absurdity. I have never understood why a first-class algebraic geometer like Hartshorne (for whom I have an undescribable admiration) could ever give such a silly definition.Use [EGA](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1960__4__5_0.pdf) 's *Définition (4.1.3)* in Chapter I, page 120 . (Beware that "preschemes" denote what we now call "schemes" and that the definition gets very simple if you only care about **open** subschemes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a set, $V(\mathfrak{a})$ is equal to the image of the closed immersion $i:\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a}) \to \operatorname{Spec} A$.  As a result, we can restrict $i$ to a homeomorphism $j:\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})\to V(\mathfrak{a})$.  We then make $V(\mathfrak{a})$ a scheme by transporting the scheme structure along $j$.  Explicitly, the structure sheaf of $V(\mathfrak{a})$ is defined as $j_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})}$.